# Отправка ajax post запроса к сервлету

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlet

Не могу никак отправить простейший запрос к сервлету средствами jQuery. Но при этом, если отправляю через форму, то все работает на ура.
Ниже привожу index.html, из которого хочу отправить логин пользователя. login.js, в котором формирую сам запрос, SerletStore.java сам сервлет. И структура всего проекта.

**login.js**
Единственный  более менее работающий url = "http://localhost:8080/testservlet/post", а они "/testservlet/post", "testservlet/post", "/post," "post" вызывают ошибку 404.

```
function addNewVoting() {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var body = 'name=' + encodeURIComponent("name") +
          '&surname=' + encodeURIComponent("surname");

        xhr.open("POST", 'http://localhost:8080/testservlet/post', true)
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

        xhr.send(body);
    };

    function addNewVoting1() {

        var user = {
            "firstName": "vlad"
        }

        var JSONString = JSON.stringify(user);

        var url = "http://localhost:8080/testservlet/post";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "post",
            data: JSONString,
            contentType: "application/json",
            error:function (message) {

                var JSONObject = JSON.parse(message);
                console.log(JSONObject);

            },
            success:function (data) {

                var JSONObject = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(JSONObject);

            },
            headers: {
                "Accept":"application/json",
                "Accept-Language":"en",
                "Cache-Control":"max-age=3600"
            }
        });
    };
```

При вызове второй функции выводит это:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/login.css">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="login">
    <form id="form" name="form-login"><!--  action="store" method="POST"> -->
        <span class="fontawesome-user"></span>
        <input type="text" id="user" name="username" placeholder="Имя пользователя">
        <span class="fontawesome-lock"></span>
        <input type="password" id="pass" name="password" placeholder="Пароль">
        <input type="input" id="login-submit" value="Вход">
    </form>

    <input style="margin-left: 30px; margin-top: 10px" type="button" onclick="addNewVoting()" value="TAKE" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**ServletStore.java**

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet(name="post", urlPatterns = "/post")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
        writer.print("Hello");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doPost(req, resp);
    }
}
```

**Структура проекта**:

[image: Структура проекта]

Может поможет еще такой скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же я экспериментировал с contentType, и либо я это делал не правильно, либо тоже не работает ничего. Прошу помочь!!!

Comment: А вас не смущает то что даже до функции обработки запроса не доходит т.к. ссылка не верна? 
            Вы пытаетесь обработать операцию по этой ссылке ChallengeClient/store, когда прорегистрировали только /store

Comment: @GenCloud Если пишу просто "/store" там тоже никак, к сожалению

Comment: Что значит "не могу отправить"? У вас вылетает alert с текстом "Возникла ошибка"?

Comment: @GenCloud, Я обновил пост и могу ответить, что ни /store, ни ChallengeClient/store, ни с localhost не работает

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Да вылетал alert, но я уже не помню в какой ситуации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В методе `doPost()` вашего сервлета вы только вызываете `doPost()` абстрактного родительского класса HttpServlet, то есть фактически у вашего сервлета нет обработчика post-запросов. Но из скрипта вы отправляете именно post-запрос. Поэтому и получаете ошибку 405 "Метод не поддерживается".

Кроме того, я вижу, что вы уже понаворочили лишнего в скрипте. Определитесь, как хотите отправлять данные из скрипта в сервлет. Более простой вариант - в виде параметров запроса. Тогда скрипт будет выглядеть так:

```
var userObj = {
    "userName": "vlad"
}

var url = "http://localhost:8080/test/post";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "post",
    data: userObj,
    error: function(message) {
        console.log(message);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

А метод `doPost()` сервлета так:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String userName = req.getParameter("userName");
    if(userName == null || "".equals(userName.trim())){
        userName = "Anonymous";
    }

    String greetings = "Hello " + userName;

    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().write(greetings);
}
```

Если же отправлять в виде данных JSON, то скрипт будет таким:

```
var userObj = {
    "userName": "vlad"
}

var userJson = JSON.stringify(userObj);

var url = "http://localhost:8080/test/post";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "post",
    data: userJson,
    contentType: "application/json",
    error: function(message) {
        console.log(message);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

А код метода `doPost()` существенно усложнится и потребует для работы зависимости [org.json.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json):

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String userName = "Anonymous";
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;

    BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        sb.append(line);

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject =  new JSONObject(sb.toString());
        userName = jsonObject.getString("userName");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        //throw new IOException("Error parsing JSON request string");
    }

    String greetings = "Hello " + userName;

    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().write(greetings);
}
```